# Two different calculations in one line

Tags: c++

wanted to ask if it is possible to add ( or any other operator ) to a couple of variables, in one line

```
int x = 5;
int y = 9;

x += 5;
y += 5;
```

I've tried

```
x, y += 5;
```

which doesn't work, so I wanted to know if there is a way to implement this kind of line

Comment: What about `x += 5; y += 5`? I don't think you'll do it any other way.

Comment: What would be the benefit?

Comment: This wouldn't even work in Python. WaiHaLees suggestion is a good way to obfuscate the code. Just don't do it.

Comment: Regardless of if you can, you shouldn't. New-line characters are free, feel free to use them liberally!

Comment: I smell a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What's your actual issue?

Answer (score 2):

Taking "one line" to mean "one statement", you could use the *expression separator operator* and write

```
x += 5, y += 5;
```

which can be useful if you want to assign the result of that to the value of the incremented `y`. Although that said, even in a code base of 1,000,000 lines, it would be unlikely to encounter a legitimate use of such a construct.

If you wanted to give the required meaning to `x, y += 5;`, I think you could achieve it if you were able to change the *types* of `x` and `y` to a class that overloads `,`; you may need some *actor* idioms too: the difficulty is getting the `5` to apply to `x` too.

Saying all that, if you were able to tolerate

```
x += y += 5
```

for `x` being a `Foo` type, say, then

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int m):m(m){};
    operator int(){return m;}
    Foo operator+=(Foo f)
    {
        m += f.m;
        return f; // this is the idiosyncrasy
    }
    int m;
};
```

does the job, with test

```
int main() {
    Foo x{1}, y{2};
    x += y += 5;
    std::cout << "x " << x << " y " << y << '\n';
}
```

Comment: *"expression separator operator"* ..hmmn, :-). I thought it was simply called the ["*comma operator*"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)?

Comment: @WhiZTiM: My operator table calls it the "expression separator operator".

Comment: The comma operator has lower precedence than assignment so `x, y += 5` is equivalent to `x , (y += 5)`.   Carrying the value `5` over so it can be added to `x` would be non-trivial .... it would take significantly more than overloading an `operator,()`.   It would also be necessary to overload assignment operators (`+=`, `-=`, `+`, etc) to make things work ..... which would result in a class with pretty confusing behaviour for developers.

Comment: @Peter: Absolutely. I'd love to spend the afternoon figuring this out (I think it is workable with actors), but alas I have a Java bug to look at.

Answer (score 2):

There is (to my knowledge) no inbuilt operator or function in C++ to apply such operations to multiple variables instead of just one.

You could define a function that takes three or more operators and call that:

```
void multiAdder(int valueToAdd, int& firstVariable, int& secondVariable)
{
    firstVariable += valueToAdd;
    secondVariable += valueToAdd;
}

void doSomething()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    multiAdder(5, a, b);
}
```

That said, I would advise against doing something like that, as it would make your code MUCH harder to read and to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing's stopping you doing this in a class.

```
struct Adder {
   int x;
   int y;

   Adder& operator += (int v) {
      x += v;
      y += v;
   }
};


int main() {
    Adder x;
    x += 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a tuple

```
tie(x, y) = make_tuple(x + 5, y + 5);
```

But I don't see any advantage of this approach over doing it in two separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it is in one line without using the comma operator:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 9;

x += (y+=5) - (y-5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always roll your own:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::tuple<T&, U&> operator+= (std::tuple<T&, U&> p, int x)
{
    std::get<0>(p) += x;
    std::get<1>(p) += x;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int s = 3;
    float t = 5.5;
    std::tie(s, t) += 7;
    // 10, 12.5
    cout << "s = " << s << ", t = " << t << endl;
}
```

Generalising to arbitrary tuples left as an exercise.